# How do you implement archive menu for blog system into rails3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs

When you go to blog page, you will see the archive list on the menu.
In most cases, it shows something like this

```
'Archive'

2012(78)
 -December(1)
 -November(5)
 -October(10)
 ...
2011(215)
2010(365)
```

I'm confident to make blog posting system by using scaffold.
But I have no idea how to make this Archive:(
Anyone come up with good idea to implement this to app easily???

Need your help!!

Comment: You can see my answer for the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425839/creating-blog-archive-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h3>Archives </h3>
<% if @posts.to_a.empty? %>
<div class="post">
    <p>No articles found...</p>
</div>
<% else %>
<% current_month = 0 %>  
<% current_year = 0 %>
<% for article in @posts %> 
  <% if (article.created_at.year != current_year)
     current_year = article.created_at.year
   %>
      <h3 class="archiveyear"><%= article.created_at.year%></h3>
<% end %>
<% if (article.created_at.month != current_month || article.created_at.year != current_year) 
 current_month = article.created_at.month 
 current_year = article.created_at.year
%>  

<h4 class="archivemonth"><%= (Date::MONTHNAMES[article.created_at.month]) %></h4>
<% end %>
<div class="archivepost">
<%= link_to article.title, article_path(article), :remote => true %> on <%= article.created_at.strftime('%A')%> - <%= article.created_at.strftime('%d') + "th"%>
</div>
<% end -%>
<%end %>
```

This may help you. I ve not included the number of counts in this code. Actually m figuring how to do it. If u can let me know.

Also in the controller ive done this.

```
@posts = Article.order("created_at DESC")
```

The `@posts` is an `array` so the items inside it ll be ordered and then i can fetch the records according to it ordering.

Thanks.