# Creating blog archive in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @posts = Post.published    

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
 end

  def show    
  .
  .
  end

  def month
    @posts_by_month = Post.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC").group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
end
```

posts#month View:

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |monthname, posts| %>
<p><%= monthname %></p>
<div>
    <ul>
        <% posts.each do |post| %>
            <li><p><%= post.title %></p></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>

<% end %>
```

posts#index view:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<%= render :partial => @posts %>

<h2>Blog archive</h2>
<%= ?I want link to single months archive here? %>
```

I'm creating a blog in rails and I thought I would add an archive section that you commonly see in the sidebar of many blogs. When I navigate to the `posts#month` view it displays the month as a heading and lists all the posts made during that month.

What I want to do now is have a list of months that posts where made on the `posts#index` view with each month linked to the `posts#month` view described above.

I'm not sure what to put on the `posts#index` view to accomplish this. Any ideas on what to put there or a better way to implement this would be great.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I am always do it by this way for grouping:

```
@posts_by_month = Post.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC").group_by { |post| post.created_at.beginning_of_month }
```

Then create for example `posts/_post_archive.html.erb`:

```
<div id="post-archive">
  <% @posts_by_month.each do |month, posts| %>
    <h4><%= "#{month.strftime('%B %Y')} (#{posts.count}):" %></h4>
   <ul>
     <% for post in posts %>
       <li><%= link_to post.title, post %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And where it will be needed write this `<%= render :partial => "posts/post_archive" %>`

**UPDATE:**

In your controller create action:

```
def by_year_and_month
  @posts = Post.where("YEAR(created_at) = ? AND MONTH(created_at) = ? ", params[:year], params[:month]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

In your `routes.rb`:

```
match 'posts/by_year_and_month/:year/:month' => 'posts#by_year_and_month', :as=> :posts_by_year_and_month
```

And modifying our `posts/_posts_archive.html.erb`:

```
<h4><%= link_to "#{month.strftime('%B %Y')} (#{posts.count}):", posts_by_year_and_month_path(:year=> month.year, :month => month.month) %></h4>
```

Comment: Yeah this is similar to what I have already. This provides a list of posts made during a month. What I'm trying to do is create a link on the index page called `August` for example that navigates to a page that lists the posts during the month August. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: An example is this blog http://sethgodin.typepad.com/. Look at the left hand side in the archive section. Notice how there are months and if you click the month it displays posts from that month. This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I get this error `undefined local variable or method posts_by_year_and_month`

Comment: Sorry in link_to add `_path` to `posts_by_year_and_month` it should look like `posts_by_year_and_month_path(:year=> month.year, :month => month.month)`, answer was updated

Comment: And add ':' to :as => :posts_by_year_and_month

Answer (score 2):

In case someone try this for Postgres, the above method will not work.

```
def by_year_and_month
  @posts = Post.where("YEAR(created_at) = ? AND MONTH(created_at) = ? ", params[:year], params[:month]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

**so you can do it like this,**

```
def by_year_and_month
@posts = Post.where('extract(year  from created_at) = ?', params[:year]).where('extract(month  from created_at) = ?', params[:month]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I knew i'd seen your post before, and I ended up needing it for this exact reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In PostsController

```
def index
  @posts = Post.published    
  @grouped_posts = Post.select("COUNT( * ) AS posts, MONTHNAME( created_at ) AS MONTH , YEAR( created_at ) AS YEAR").group("MONTH, YEAR").order("YEAR, MONTH( created_at )")
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
 end
```

and then in view index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<%grouped_posts.each do |rec|%>
<%=link_to "#{rec.month} #{rec.year} (#{rec.posts})", {:controller => "posts", :action => "month", :month => rec.month, :year => rec.year} %>
<%end%>
<%= render :partial => @posts %>

<h2>Blog archive</h2>
<%= ?I want link to single months archive here? %>
```

And then change the month action in posts_controller to accept two parameters params[:month] & params[:year]

Hope this will help