# Trouble creating Archive of Blog Posts in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425839/creating-blog-archive-in-rails/18425949#18425949) in an attempt to setup an Archive for my posts.

And I am going well up until the point where I am trying to create a loop to list out each Post within each month.

I am getting this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "from": syntax error: SELECT "bets".* FROM "bets" WHERE (extract(year  from created_at) = '2016') AND (extract(month  from created_at) = '2')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bets_by_month = Bet.all.group_by { |bet| bet.created_at.beginning_of_month }
  end

  def by_year_and_month
    @bets = Bet.where('extract(year  from created_at) = ?', params[:year]).where('extract(month  from created_at) = ?', params[:month]).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

And my by_year_and_month view looks like this:

```
<%= @bets.each do |bet| %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
'extract(year  from created_at) = ?'
```

this syntax is incorrect.  Try this instead:

```
"strftime('%Y', created_at) = ?"
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax is now correct and I'm returning an array when I sort by Year. However, when I'm also factoring in the sorting by month, it is returning a blank array.

Comment: That sounds like a different question to me.