# Rails blog archive search by date

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am doing a ruby on rails archive blog.The backend works fine but the year displays seperately as you can see in the below image

[image]

As you can see in the image above the years are coming seperately.But if I give some blog in the same month it works fine as you can see in the month of `august 2014`(accident,Politics) but not for 2014.

This is the controller

```
@posts_by_month = Cutting.find(:all, :order => "date DESC").group_by { |post| post.date.beginning_of_month }
```

the view

```
<div class="easy-tree" style="float:left;width:300px;background: #aaaaaa;">
   <%# @post_months.sort.reverse.each do |month, posts| %>
    <%@posts_by_month.each do |month, posts|%>
    <ul>
      <li><%=h month.strftime("%G")%>
        <ul>
          <li><%=h month.strftime("%B") %>
              <!--li ><%=h month.strftime %>-->
            <ul>
            <% for post in posts %>
              <li style="background: #aaaaaa;"class="getid" name ="<%=post.id%>"><%=h link_to post.subject%></li>
            <% end %>
                </ul>
              <!--/li-->            
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

I am using easy-tree for getting the ui for

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement archive menu for blog system into rails3 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835631/how-do-you-implement-archive-menu-for-blog-system-into-rails3-app)

Comment: the above suggestion doesnt help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 @posts = Cutting.all(:select => "id, subject, date, created_at", :order => "date DESC")
 @post_months = @posts.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_year }
```

And on your views

```
<div class="easy-tree" style="float:left;width:300px;background: #aaaaaa;">
    <% @post_months.sort.reverse.each do |year, postss| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%=h year.strftime("%G")%>
        <% postss.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }.each do |month, posts| %>
        <ul>
          <li><%=h month.strftime("%B") %>  
            <ul>
            <% for post in posts %>
              <li style="background: #aaaaaa;" class="getid" name ="<%=post.id%>"><%=h link_to post.subject %></li>
            <% end %>
                </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Output :

[image: output]

Comment: This works thank you.  I'm interested to know if it is considered bad design to put the nested group_by logic into the view.  I was thinking about constructing a nested hash in the controller and then just iterating over that in the view.  Would this be a best practice or is this overkill?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is your query is **grouping the posts by month only** - meaning you're going to receive an object back based on their month alone. Although this may show the `year` / `month` as you wish, the underlying structure of the object will be centered on months, rather than years (as you wish).

A way to test this will be to call `@posts_by_month.debug` in your view, allowing you to see exactly what the object looks like. I would surmise it will be just be sorted by months

--

**Fix**

The way to fix this will be group by the `year` and then by the `month`. I've never done this, but have [researched](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=35337) & found the bottom line is you need to group by `year` and then by `month`, like this:

```
@posts_by_month = Post.all.order(date: :desc).group("year(created_at)").group("month(created_at)")
```

My example uses [`.group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) with reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902974/grouping-by-week-month-etc-activerecord)